# Comparing 2 different image

Tags: matlab

I am trying to compare multiple image using corr2 to see the similarity in correlation.

```
for i=1:2
    first_img = imread(sprintf('%g.jpg',i));
    first_size = size(first_img);
    size_temp = size(first_size);
    max_size = max(size_temp);
    if max_size == 3
        first_img = rgb2gray(first_img);
        first_size = size(first_img);
    end
    for j=i+1:2
        second_img = imread(sprintf('%g.jpg',j));
        second_size = size(second_img);
        size_temp = size(second_size);
        max_size = max(size_temp);
        if max_size == 3
            second_img = rgb2gray(second_img);
            second_size = size(second_img);
        end
        if i == j
            continue;end
        if first_size ~= second_size
            continue;end
        if first_size == second_size
            correlation_fs = corr2(first_img,second_img);
            if correlation_fs == 1
                fprintf('%g is the same as %g\n',first_img,second_img);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

now, the problem show up when the first image compared to the 3rd dummy image which is exactly the same as the first image.

```
219 is the same as 219
220 is the same as 220
221 is the same as 221
221 is the same as 222
224 is the same as 223
222 is the same as 221
221 is the same as 222
223 is the same as 224
218 is the same as 236
242 is the same as 232
217 is the same as 219
226 is the same as 228
220 is the same as 229
241 is the same as 251
254 is the same as 253
250 is the same as 247
253 is the same as 253
252 is the same as 248
237 is the same as 224
217 is the same as 218
225 is the same as 219
219 is the same as 223
219 is the same as 214
222 is the same as 237
```

I don't know why this is showing up, it should print that image 1 is the same as image 3, at least is what i want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing out the entire image matrices instead of the image number. Try:

```
fprintf('%g is the same as %g\n',i,j)
```

Think about what `first_img` is, it's a matrix of pixel intensities. So you're printing out all the pixel values.

Answer (score 0):

```
 fprintf('%g is the same as %g\n',first_img,second_img);
```

Here you are passing two images as arguments. You should have passed the image numbers instead.

```
 fprintf('%g is the same as %g\n', i, j);
```